# Variáveis e o *ngFor não funcionam no Html - Angular

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

Pessoal quando quero usar o *ngFor="let animal of produtos">
no html no meu projeto angular não funciona não da para usar e as variáveis dentro do {{}} também não funcionam !

CÓDIGO HTML

```
<div class="class">
  <h1>Produtos:</h1>
  <ul>
    <li *ngFor="let animal of produtos">
      Nome: {{ animal.name }} - tipo: {{ animal.type }}
      <button (click)="showAge(animal)">Show Age</button>
      <button (click)="removeAnimal(animal)">Excluir</button>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <h3>{{ animalDetails }}</h3>
</div>
```

Como mostra a imagem ele não funciona diferente da video aula que estou acompanhando!

[inserir a descrição da imagem aqui](https://i.stack.imgur.com/knGUQ.png)

imagem da video aula:

[inserir a descrição da imagem aqui](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0krtk.png)

Comment: A única coisa que está diferente é de **`of animals`** para **`of produtos`**. Só podemos ajudar com esta informação!

Answer (score -2):

Veja se o array dentro do seu typescript que você quer percorrer com o *ngFor está com o nome correto. No vídeo mostra como **animals** você usou **produtos**, a variável que vc chama no html e no typescript precisam possuir o mesmo nome. Se isso não resolver pode ser a importação do CommonModule.

Para utilizar *ngIf, *ngFor e outras diretivas nativas do Angular você precisa fazer a importação do módulo nativo CommonModule dentro do módulo onde seu componente foi declarado.

```
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule
  ],
  declarations: [
    MeuComponenteComponent
  ]
})

export class MeuModuloModule { }
```

Certifique-se que fez a importação, esse tipo de problema não emite erro então pode passar despercebido mesmo.